# How do i Automate the Magento projects with the selenium webdriver? Also to prepare Automation test cases for the Magento Projects?

Tags: automated-tests

Can anyone tell me that how to prepare test cases for Magento projects to Automate it and also tell me the work flow of Magento e-commerce projects in Automation